# $\int_{\mathbb R} |f(x)| dx < \infty \implies \sum_{n\in \mathbb Z} |f(n)| < \infty $?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, lp-spaces

Put, $C_{0} (\mathbb R)=\{f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb C: f \text { is continuous on} \ \mathbb R \  \text  {and } \lim_{|x|\to \pm \infty}f(x)=0 \}$(= Continuous functions on $\mathbb R$ vanishing at $\infty$)

Let $f\in C_{0} (\mathbb R)$ such that $\int_{\mathbb R} |f(x)| dx < \infty $.

**My Question**: Can we expect $\sum_{n\in \mathbb Z} |f(n)| < \infty$; Or, we get a counter example, that is, $\sum_{n\in \mathbb Z} |f(n)| = \infty $ ?

Comment: No. Let the graph of $f$ consist of spikes centered at the positive integers with the $n$'th spike having height $1/n$ and base of width $1/n$ ($f$ has value $0$ except for the spikes).

Comment: It is OK if $|f|$ is unimodal.

Comment: @GEdgar; I am sorry, I could not follow; can you explain bit more(You mean to say under some condition on $f$ , we will have positive answer?  what is unimodal ?); thanks a lot; -\).

Comment: Unimodal: there is a value $a$ (the mode) and $|f|$ is decreasing on $x>a$, increasing on $x<a$.  Now the usual proof of the integral test will show $$\int_{\mathbb R} |f(x)| dx < \infty \Longleftrightarrow \sum_{n\in \mathbb Z} |f(n)| < \infty$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define $f$ to be $0$ everywhere except on intervals of the form $[n-1/n, n+1/n]$, $n$ an integer greater than $1$. On an interval $[n-1/n , n+1/n ]$ of this form, let $f$ be  non-negative, continuous, and piecewise linear with maximum value $1/n$ at the midpoint of the interval and value $0$ at the endpoints.

Then $\int |f|\le\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty 2/n^2<\infty$ and $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty|f(n)|=\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty 1/n=\infty$.

Comment: Ah, clever! So the sum depends only on the heights of the spikes, but the integral (area) depends critically on the width as well. Nice!

Comment: @MPW Yes; that's the crucial observation.

Comment: @DM;  beautiful answer; Thanks, -\).

Answer (score 2):

This is a picture of David Mitra's example in the comment:
[image]

Comment: good; thanks;-\).